# Solr Statistics on the score of the documents?

Tags: solr

I want to get some Histogram-like statistics on the scores of my documents in Solr.

Let me expand a bit more :
Lets say my solr results are in the form of

```
userid,score
A,4
B,4
C,3
D,3
E,3
F,2
```

(I have customized the Similarity class to give me an integer score for the documents.)
I want to get some basic stats (count of userid per score )
I am looking for a result like

```
4,2
3,3
2,1
```

Is this even possible to do in Solr ? 
I can surely get the first set of result and calculate the stats but I am expecting results back in millions of rows.

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't think it is possible with Solr.
Faceting can be an option, however as Score is not a field defined in schema and maintained in the Index, it would not be possible to facet on the score field.